# What type of material should be used to fill a gap in between my fireplace tiles?

Tags: fireplace, grout

I recently repainted the tiles and grout of my fireplace, using the appropriate sander, primer and paint recommended by Benjamin Moore. I then inserted a new set of fireplace doors. I was hoping the doors would hide a gap in the grout that had fallen out. But, as you can see in the photos, the gap still shows at the top center of the doors.

I'd like to fill this gap but have found lots of conflicting advice on the Internet. Can anyone recommend an effective material that can be painted?
Because the gap is on the outside of the hearth, I don't think we'd need a super-high-heat-resistant material.

Also, I'm a novice and am not sure that "grout" is the correct word for what is between the tiles.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The hottest part of the surround will probably be at the top, where the hole is.  So, I would suggest that you keep away from flexible type grouts.  Normal grout would probably be okay.

But I would recommend that you used a high temperature grout such as this.  It exists for a reason.  If they dont sell it in a small container, then try the normal grout.  It won't be dangerous, it won't catch fire.

[image]

[image]